# How to stop all web-workers? They're draining my battery

Tags: web-application, malware, browser, web

A great many websites leave "web workers" running in the background even after you've left their website and closed the browser tab.

I'm told that the only way to kill them all is to clear my cookies. But what would be inconvenient, because I'd have to log in to websites all over again.

Is there a way to stop/kill web worker processes without clearing cookies?

I'm using Firefox.

Also, how can I get the source code to these web workers?

Comment: “…running in the background even after you've left their website and closed the browser tab.” I contend that is not the case. If you close a tab or even navigate away from it and put it in the background, web services should not work at all. Seems like a wild good chase; also known as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319). What is the real issue? Your battery draining? On what kind of machine?

Answer (score 0):

For firefox you can see and unregister all service workers (the only type that can outlive the origin tab) by going to `about:serviceworkers` in the url bar

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, cd into ~/.mozilla/firefox.

Then cd into the profile directory.

Then find serviceworker.txt, which should list some/all of them.